# Ember.js and handlebars each helper, with subviews

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm triyng to use the view helper inside my {{#each}} template blocks without using global paths (my controllers create and destroy their own views).

Examples. Given a view with a myList array property, and an itemButton child view:

This will work

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" name="my-list-view">
{{#each myList}} <!-- App.myListView.myList -->

    {{view App.myListView.itemButton}} {{title}}

{{/each}}
</script>
```

This will not:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" name="my-list-view">
{{itemButton}} <!-- works fine outside the each -->
{{#each myList}}

    {{view itemButton}} {{title}} <!-- itemButton view not found -->

{{/each}}
</script>
```

I do not appear to be able to access the parent view from the each view helper (or in fact access anything other than the properties of the objects being iterated).

**The hacky workarounds** I've come up with are:

- Add the view I want to use to the items I'm iterating over.

or

1. Creating a collectionView in App.myListView
2. Create an itemViewClass view in that collection view class
3. Move the itemButton view inside the itemViewClass
4. Replace {{#each}} with {{#collection}}

or

- Create a custom handlebars helper for iteration.

Both of these options seem horrible.
Surely there's a better alternative than creating 2 new classes (and nesting 4 views deep) just to iterate over a list, though. Is there a replacement handlebars helper I can use instead?

---

## Workaround implementations

### Option #1 : Modifing the content array

http://jsfiddle.net/FQEZq/3/
Disadvantages: Having to add the view to each model instance just for iteration.

### Option #2 : Custom collection view

http://jsfiddle.net/ST24Y/1/
Disadvantages: Now you have two additional views that you do not need / want,  and less control of markup. References from the child view to the parent instance now requires parentView.parentView.parentView.

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#each` is too limited for your requirements. You can make it work if you're willing to use a global path to the view you want to nest within the `#each`. Otherwise, your collection view approach is best. Adding the view to the model instance is likely to muddy your app design something fierce, so I would avoid that.

One idea to keep your templates clean is to take advantage of `Ember.View` properties like:

- `collectionView` - Return the nearest ancestor that is an `Ember.CollectionView`
- `itemView` - Return the nearest ancestor that is a direct child of an `Ember.CollectionView`
- `contentView` - Return the nearest ancestor that has the property content.

Answer (score 0):

The big thing here - options.

Hooks for how you wish to use a template are available. These are:

```
<-- render templates/name.js -->
{{partial 'name'}}

<-- render views/name.js -->
{{view 'name'}}

<-- render views/name1.js with controllers/name2.js -->
{{render 'name1' 'name2'}}

<!-- see also: -->
{{output}}
{{output 'named'}}
{{yield}}
```

An example variant of your initial template showing 4 different options:

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='my-list-view'>
  <h2>Option 1</h2>

  {{#each myList}}
    {{! the 2nd parameter will look for itemButtonController }}
    {{render 'itembutton' itemButton}}
  {{/each}}

  <h2>Option 2</h2>
  {{#each myList}}
    {{! using an Ember Component }}
    {{#item-button }}
      some static text OR {{dynamic}}
    {{/item-button}}
    <!-- in component/item-button.hbs add {{yield}} for where you want the static content to output -->
  {{/each}}

  <h2>Option 3</h2>
  {{#each myList}}
    {{! if the button is to be a link }}
    {{#link-to 'route' parameter tagName='button' classNames='btn'}}
      {{title}}
    {{/link-to}}
  {{/each}}

  <h2>Option 4</h2>
  <p>Ludicrous example showing almost every reference option!</p>

  {{! focus the context on subview data }}
  {{#with someArrayOrCollectionOfView}}
    {{! prepend type to add context - here returning back up to this view's properties }}
    {{#each view.myList}}
      {{! this is equivalent to someArrayOrCollectionOfView[x].name }}
      {{name}}

      {{! a button that hooks in route, model, and 2 controllers, and applies a target for the output when clicked }}
      {{#link-to 'page' controllers.page.nextPage target='outlet' tagName='button' disabledWhen=controller.disableNext }}
        {{model.buttonName}}
      {{/link-to}}
    {{/each}}
  {{/with}}

  {{! generic default target (automatic) }}
  {{outlet}}

  {{! example of a named target }}
  {{outlet 'footerlinks'}}
</script>
```

Mmmm... reference for further reading:
[Ember.Handlebars.helpers](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_bind-attr)